# Oracle connection prioritizer

Tags: oracle, concurrency, oledb

Maybe that will sound odd, but I need to schedule priority on oracle connections.  It goes like that:

I have one main 'connection' that will pump data out of oracle, and it should be as fast as it can be.

I have two other connections that should (ideally) use all oracle resources not dedicated to the first query.

Is there a way to do this, by means of connection string parameters or such?

If you mean to suggest a scenario where I wait for first connection to do its job, then start others, that's not OK, because I don't know when user will start the first one, so I should either abort 'background' queries, or let them finish - which they do for two minutes on some occasions - they pump lot of data from the DB engine to the client ( [Fastest OLEDB read from ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501195/fastest-oledb-read-from-oracle) )

BTW - answer: "There is no way of prioritizing SQL statements in Oracle" would also be great coming from some Oracle authority!  It would enable me to search other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Resource Manager to do this sort of stuff. Unfortunately, I've never used it in anger, so I can't help on the actual configuration.

See: http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/dbrm.htm

Comment: I had thought of this as well, but resource manager will cap the resources and prevent execution as opposed to assigning a priority.  I think a roll-your-own solution is needed.